# how to suppress a line segment along left-hand side edge of a tabular environment?

Tags: tables, border

I do not want the extra line above the "Websites" cell, (circled in red). How do I remove this?

Here are my LaTeX commands:

```
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|}
\cline{2-3} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{License Numbers} \\
\hline
Website & Present & Not Present \\ \cline{1-3}
HiPages    & 527 & 72 \\ 
Airtasker  & 73   & 20 \\
GumTree    & 26 & 5 \\
Service Seeking  & 151 & 20 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

and my output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you replace

```
\cline{2-3} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{License Numbers} \\
```

with

```
\cline{2-3} \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{License Numbers} \\
```

Oh, and I'd definitely replace `\cline{1-3}` with `\hline`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
%\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}

\begin{tabular}{ |l|c|c|}
%\cline{2-3} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{License Numbers} \\
\cline{2-3} \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{License Numbers} \\
\hline
Website & Present & Not Present \\ 
\hline %%\cline{1-3}
HiPages    & 527 & 72 \\ 
Airtasker  & 73   & 20 \\
GumTree    & 26 & 5 \\
Service Seeking  & 151 & 20 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You, this works